# How to use Ruby Net::HTTP to download an image without storing it?

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm writing a script to warm a CDN cache. I need to make a request to download an image, but I don't actually need to load it into memory or storing it to disk. From what I've read, `Net::HTTP.get` will load the image response into memory. How can I stream the download without taking up space in memory or writing to disk?

Comment: stream it how? HTTP does not hold onto a connection.  Request goes out,  server responds, connection closed.  So in your case, you're requesting an image, the server will respond with the image and the connection is closed.  Would simply knowing the image exists on the server work for your scenario?

Comment: @Anthony I don't think this is true. HTTP servers can support persistent connections with keep alive settings. Also imagine a 100TB file download. You're not going to download the whole file in one, all-or-nothing, session. The client is going to want to store those bytes received somewhere so it doesn't have to download the whole file all over again.